# vim: Separate virtualenv for vim plugins and application code

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, python-venv

I have multiple vim plugins (ropevim, taskwarrior etc.) which depend on python libraries. These libraries are installed in system python3

When I am working on a python project, the virtual environment for that project does not have these libraries. Resulting in these plugins not working and dumping a ton of error messages on the console.

Is it possible to ensure that vim always uses the same virtual environment (or system python env) for its plugins irrespective of what the shell virtualenv is?

Comment: Maybe ask there: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unable to migrate the question to vi.stackexchange.com ...